# How to modify specific column using sed or awk based on specific pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I have a csv file looks like this:

```
c1,c2,c3,http://aaa.com/blblbblb\nhttp://bbb.com/sdsdsds\nhttp://ccc.com\nhttp://foo.com/ghghghgh

cc1,cc2,cc3,http://eee.com/blblbblb\nhttp://foo.com/sdsdsds\nhttp://fff.com\nhttp://ttt.com/ghghghgh

ccc1,ccc2,ccc3,http://foo.com/blblbblb\nhttp://vvv.com/sdsdsds\nhttp://foo.com/nmnmnmnm\nhttp://qqq.com\nhttp://kkk.com/ghghghgh
```

is it possible manipulate above csv file and export as follows: (using `sed` or `awk` or similar bash commands)

```
c1,c2,c3,http://foo.com/ghghghgh 

cc1,cc2,cc3,http://foo.com/sdsdsds

ccc1,ccc2,ccc3,http://foo.com/blblbblb;http://foo.com/nmnmnmnm
```

Actually i want to manipulate only 4th column and Remain `http://foo.com/{some string}` pattern (in other words, extract links from 4th column when contain foo.com domain)

Comment: Do the `\n` mean `'newline'` ?

Comment: yes \n mean 'newline'.but Is ineffective in csv file.

Comment: It is matter whether each http on separate line or not. What output produce `cat file.csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '
    s|http://foo.com|@|g #replace `foo.com` domain with rare symbol
    /./s/\\n\|$/;/g      #replace `\n` by `;`  and add it to end 
    s/http[^@]*;//g      #remove all domain(s) without `foo.com`
    s|@|http://foo.com|g #place `foo.com` back
    s/;$//               #remove `;` from the end of line
    ' csv.file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
cat your_csv.csv | sed 's/\\n/,/g' | cut -d ',' -f 4
```

`sed` will change all the `\n`s to `,` and `cut` chooses the 4th field when the delimiter is `,`